# C++ make_shared and .get()

Tags: c++14

I am new to using shared and unique pointers, and I am trying to make a Linked List using shared pointers, however, my program keeps crashing randomly.

Please send me useful advice and/or links books to read for my better understanding, this is a new C++ feature for me.

I'm trying to solve the LeetCode question https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/description/

And the API requires ListNode* to be passed in as arguments, so I'm just trying to create some test data without using naked new...

Random crashes occur using make_shared:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  ListNode* list1 = (make_shared<ListNode>(2)).get();
  list1->next = (make_shared<ListNode>(4)).get();
  list1->next->next = (make_shared<ListNode>(3)).get();

  ListNode* list2 = (make_shared<ListNode>(5)).get();
  list2->next = (make_shared<ListNode>(6)).get();
  list2->next->next = (make_shared<ListNode>(4)).get();

  Solution solution;
  ListNode* result = solution.addTwoNumbers(list1, list2);
```

This works OK:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  ListNode* list1 = new ListNode(2);
  list1->next = new ListNode(4);
  list1->next->next = new ListNode(3);

  ListNode* list2 = new ListNode(5);
  list2->next = new ListNode(6);
  list2->next->next = new ListNode(4);

  Solution solution;
  ListNode* result = solution.addTwoNumbers(list1, list2);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `make_shared(...).get()`?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `shared_ptr<T>` destroys the pointed object as soon as there is no instance of `shared_ptr<>` pointing to it.

When you do:

```
(make_shared<ListNode>(2)).get();
```

You create a temporary (lives until the current satement has finished executing for every intent and purpose) instance of `std::shared_ptr<ListNode>`.

Since you never assign that `shared_ptr<>` to anything else, once that line of code finishes executing, and the `shared_ptr<>` is destroyed, ther number of `shared_ptr<>` pointing to that new ListNode instance falls to 0 and the ListNode itself is destroyed. The pointer to it you got by calling `get()` is now a dangling pointer.

What you **should** be doing is the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<ListNode> list1 = make_shared<ListNode>(2);
```